# display a barcode with Zend_PDF

Tags: zend-framework, zend-pdf

Hy guys,

how can i display a barcode with Zend_PDF ?

this is my code:

```
  $config = new Zend_Config(array(
                'barcode'        => 'code39',
                'barcodeParams'  => array('text' => '11020109'),
                'renderer'       => 'image',
                'rendererParams' => array('imageType' => 'gif'),
             ));
  $renderer = Zend_Barcode::factory($config)->render();
```

now how can i render it to my pdf?
i try without succes with:

```
$barcode = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($renderer);
$page->drawImage($barcode, 10, 510, 290, 550);
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get you going, there is 3 things you have to change, your renderer, your method to render the barcode to the pdf and for some obscure reason, you have to include a font to your Zend_Barcode or you will get an error

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

// Your font (path might differ)
Zend_Barcode::setBarcodeFont(APPLICATION_PATH . '\..\data\resources\fonts\arial.ttf'); 

$config = new Zend_Config(
    array(
        'barcode'        => 'code39',
        'barcodeParams'  => array('text' => '11020109'),
        'renderer'       => 'pdf', // here is your new renderer
        'rendererParams' => array(), // you can define position offset here
    )
);

$pdfWithBarcode = Zend_Barcode::factory($config)->setResource($pdf)->draw(); // your new barcode renderer is defined here, from now on to add things to your pdf you need to use the new variable ($pdfWithBarcode)

// Save your pdf (path might differ)
$pdfWithBarcode->save(APPLICATION_PATH . '\..\data\testBarcode.pdf');
```

Comment: i try it, but receive this error: Null character is not allowed in PDF Names

Comment: The font you are setting to your `Zend_Barcode` exists in the path you have given?

Comment: do you have any special characters in your output filename?

Comment: i think no.. $pdf->save("fogliovendita.pdf");

Comment: The last line is wrong: $pdfWithBarcode is an instance of Zend_Barcode_Renderer_Pdf and you need Zend_Pdf. I think you meant $pdf->save(...); or maybe the API changed in the meanwhile (i'm looking at zf 1.12)